# Qlikview "Unexpected Exception Occurred" in Webview and on server

Tags: qlikview

I'm getting a rather strange error in `Qlikview` when either in developer (11 or 12) when i change to the webview, also when I look at the `qvw` on the server.

> Unexpected Exception Occurred

This only happens on some tabs, but always the same tab.

Happens in both Developer Version 11 or 12.

Happens in Chrome & IE.

Server Error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strangely enough this was caused by copied `Current Selection` boxes.

Whenever I copy and pasted a `Current Selection` box into another tab, that tab would get the same error.

I simply deleted and recreated the `Current Selection` box for each tab I had the error and it was resolved.